# Extending a generic class into a static inner class

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I am having issues extending an inner class with a generic abstract class.

I get an `Non-static field cannot be referenced from a static context` which is odd because the class itself is static, not necessarily the field value.

This is basically what I have:

```
// AbstractFoo.java
public abstract class AbstractFoo extends FrameLayout {
    // Some logic
}

// AbstractBar.java
public abstract class AbstractBar<T> {
    int someNumber;
    // Some logic
}

// Foo.java
public class Foo extends AbstractFoo {
    // Some logic

    // Foo.InnerFoo.java
    public static class InnerFoo extends AbstractBar<InnerFoo> {
        public InnerFoo() {
            super.someNumber = 5; // Compiler error HERE
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason I cannot access `someNumber` from `InnerFoo`. From my understanding this shouldn't cause any issues. The classes I'm extending btw is from an external library.

This is also all done with Android where minimum SDK is 24.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `public class Foo extends Foo {`???

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter sorry fixed it

Comment: someNumber should be protected to access it via a subclass.  Also, class X extends SomeGeneric<X> is really weird, if even legal.

Comment: `public InnerFoo() {..}` is not static. So it should not cause any issue. Try to post a code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @GabeSechan `X extends SomeGeneric<X>` is called the self-type pattern or CRTP. `String` uses it for instance to implement `Comparable<String>`.

Comment: The code you posted compiles just fine for me.

Comment: I figured it out, the fields are package protected (facepalm)

Comment: Apart from that visibility problem: Your code violates the most important OO principle: *information hiding / encapsulation*. No other class (not even subclasses) should know how a class stores its properties. The proper way to go here would be to pass the value as *constructor parameter* to `AbstractBar` and assign it in `AbstractBar`s constructor.

Comment: @JornVernee And I can't think of a single reason why to do it.  According to Wikipedia it allows a hack in C++ due to how C++ treats templates, but I can't find a reference to ever doing it in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The fields defined in your classes do not have an explicit access modifier which would use the default access modifier and limit the visibility to classes within the same package.

You should make the fields in `AbstractBar` as `protected` -

```
public abstract class AbstractBar<T> {
    protected int someNumber;
}
```